# Why do parameters don't get passed to this eloquent DB::raw query causing it to throw a "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" error

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this rather simple query:

```
Category::whereRaw('hierarchy LIKE ?', [$old_hierarchy . '>%'])
    ->update([
        'hierarchy' => DB::raw("REPLACE(hierarchy, ?, ?)", [$old_hierarchy, $new_hierarchy])
    ]);
```

And it keeps giving me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: update `categories` set `hierarchy` = REPLACE(hierarchy, 2020-05-25 22:30:55, first_param>%), `categories`.`updated_at` = ? where hierarchy LIKE ?)
```

Seems like no parameters are passed to the DB::raw. Any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this thing is so weird I have zero explanation for it, but here's the solution:

1) First of all you need to explicitly update `updated_at` yourself, because otherwise Laravel would try and do it itself and make a big mess out of everything.

2) For some unknown reason the initial setup simply failed to assign the variables to the placeholder `?`: `DB::raw("REPLACE(hierarchy, ?, ?)", [$old_hierarchy, $new_hierarchy])`

3) I had to do it using `setBindings`, but on top of that couldn't assign all of them through this method because they would have gotten messed up once again, so only did it for the `DB::raw` statements.

```
Category::setBindings([$old_hierarchy, $new_hierarchy, now()])
    ->whereRaw("hierarchy LIKE ?", [$old_hierarchy . '>%'])
    ->update([
        'hierarchy' => DB::raw("REPLACE(hierarchy, ?, ?)"),
        'updated_at' => DB::raw("?")
    ]);
```

If anyone has any explanation of this whole crazy thing, please let me know